# empty game object not jumping c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so im trying to make a basic character that is able to jump but it just won't. it can move and stuff but it just won't jump. I really dont know what the problem could be. here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Playermovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Interacteble focus;

    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    public Transform GroundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    void update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(GroundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `isGrounded` is working fine? try removing it from `Jump` condition if it works then problem is your ground check

Comment: Sorry but I'm not able to understand your code.    velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);   why multiply by minus? When in next line you are increasing the velocity. Please explain more clearly

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohi I removed isGrounded but its still not working